# sass/scss what is the best way to create themes?

Tags: css, sass

I'm making a multi-theme website using sass features. What I have is a theme partial that loops through a list of map that contains all features for different themes like this:

```
$themes: (
    theme1: (
        color: #000
    ),
    theme2: (
        color: #fff
    )
);

@each $theme, $map in $themes {
    .#{$theme} {
        .text{
            color: map-get($map, color);
        }
    }
}
```

and I will add whatever element needs to change with theme into that each loop so that they all get generated like:

```
.theme1 .text{ color: #000; }
.theme2 .text{ color: #fff; }
```

I wonder if there is a way to take advantage of mixin/function feature that I can custom themes in line:

```
.text{
    font-size: 12px;
    @include get-theme-component(color); // or
    color: get-theme-component(color);
}
```

and it should generate css like:

```
.theme1 .text{ color: #000; }
.theme2 .text{ color: #fff; }
```

I'm new to sass, not sure if this is doable :D